# Is eval () dangerous in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, eval

I found a similar question about the danger of eval() in the case below, **but the answer didn't solve the problem and answered If it was dangerous or not, It only suggested another method. That is why I am asking again hoping to get a new answer. Also It was posted in 2016**

So I want to pass a condition as a parameter, I know that this can be a function, but I've read that `eval ()` is 67% faster than `new function () {return ...;}`, that is why I am using eval ()

This is the code

```js
var a = [0];


function LoopWithDelay (func, delay, param, condition){

 console.log(eval (condition));
 
  if (eval (condition)) {
  func (param);
  setTimeout (LoopWithDelay, delay, func, delay, param, condition);
 }
}


function increment (x){
 x[0] += 5;
}


LoopWithDelay (increment, 1000, a, "a[0]<10" );
```

When calling the `LoopWithDelay()` function I am passing the final parameter (condition) as a string so that It is evaluated inside the function `eval (condition)`

**Is It wrong to use `eval()` in this case ?**

[edited]
My main focus is to make this code reusable and eliminate redundancy. That is why I want to pass the condition as a parameter.

Example:
In a test application where the screen flashes at different speeds depending on how much time is left.
If t = 0s flash every 2000ms 
If 10s<t<20s flash every 1000s 
etc.

Comment: It just looks as u r doing loops in the air to achieve something much simpler. The danger here is unexpected behaviors and difficulty maintaining such code. Give an example to what condition can be.

Comment: If your string is fixed then it's safe to be used inside `eval`. But if your string is fixed, then you don't need to use eval! Provide a real example

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka This is just a test, this function will be used later to manipulate the transform style of an element

Comment: In this exact case no, but will you always have 100% control over that `condition` input? Also, where did you read `eval` is 67% faster than `new Function` that number is just... magic.

Comment: I'm sure that this won't be your real production code, otherwise you would just use `if(a[0]<10)`, without any hack. If your question is about security, you should consider the danger of user inputs and network responses

Comment: I'd say this is a dangerous game of early optimization. Sure, you could do this to speed up your application, but it's at the possible risk of security issues and less maintainable code.

Comment: Then you are better off creating a function that holds staticly references to the elements you want to tweak. The function goes noware after initial instantiation, and holding a ref for an element is quicker (I never tested this, seems logical) than doing an eval that looks for an elelemnt in the dom.

Comment: I will edit the post to clarify how I want to use It. Thank you

Comment: @Kaiido https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/13695921 this post says that it is slower, the number 67% was in the third comment of the question in that page. Also this was posed  in 2008. But what I was going for is getting the faster solution even If it is only 10% faster if there is no risk

Comment: Sorry but reading that answer all I see is that eval is slower than normal code execution, that it got a bit improved in later versions of browsers, but nothing about new Function, and nothing about eval being faster than anything else (because it isn't).

Comment: Making choices based on "percentage faster" seems like a really poor use of your effort. Is 10% faster really worth using something like `eval()` if in reality that's 110 nano-seconds vs 100 nanoseconds?

Comment: Also, the comments about the speed are comparing it to passing a string to `new Function()` in the [sense used here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function), which is similar to eval. This is *much* different than passing an *actual* function reference like `() => a[0]<10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like you are just trying to make a dynamic test that can react to something that changes in your code at runtime. You would typically do this by passing a function as a parameter, not a string with code to be later "eval()ed". This is the way you typically pass "behavior" or evaluate something that is only available at runtime. And it is *very* common in javascript. This has the same behavior, but doesn't need `eval()`:

```js
var a = [0];

function LoopWithDelay(func, delay, param, condition) {

  let condition_val = condition()
  console.log(condition_val);

  if (condition_val) {
    func(param);
    setTimeout(LoopWithDelay, delay, func, delay, param, condition);
  }
}


function increment(x) {
  x[0] += 5;
}

// capture `a` in the closure of the passed-in function
LoopWithDelay(increment, 1000, a, () => a[0] < 10);
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question and added how the code is used. Yes the condition may sometimes change at runtime, but the main focus was to eliminate redundancy if it was goin to be used multiple times.